# Store resolved value of Observable for multiple use in Template

Tags: angular, rxjs

What I want to achieve in an Angular template is something like the following:

```
<div *ngIf="let resolved = (observable$ | async)">
  <span>{{resolved.property1}}</span>
  <span>{{resolved.property2}}</span>
  <span>{{resolved.property3}}</span>
</div>
```

I have an observable in the controller, the async result of which I want to use multiple times in the template. The whole `<div>` should only be rendered once the observable receives a value at all.

I am aware that the above code does not work like that because the `*ngIf` micro-syntax does not allow for this kind of `let` statement. The only way to really achieve this I've found is by creating a custom component and hand in `(observable$ | async)` as an input, so that the resolved value is available in the component's controller.

But I think this is such a standard problem that there must be a more simple solution. What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: Does `(observable$ | async) as resolved` work? Like so: `<div *ngIf="(observable$ | async) as resolved">`

Comment: Indeed! now i feel stupid for not knowing about this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are quite close it's done with `as`

```html
<div *ngIf="observable$ | async as resolved">
  <span>{{resolved.property1}}</span>
  <span>{{resolved.property2}}</span>
  <span>{{resolved.property3}}</span>
</div>
```